# BT138+MOC3063. How to calculate resistor power?

Tags: resistors, ac, triac

I want to use this schematic to control AC with maximum current of 10A
[image]

The only thing I don't understand is how calculate power of resistors (marked red)?
There are lots of such schematics on web, but nobody explains how to chose resistors.

Answer (score -1):

Мощность резисторов здесь практически не важна. Здесь главное- чтобы резисторы выдерживали большой импульсный ток (для R1: Iimp=Umax/R1~~1A или Pimp~~300W). Но средняя мощность практически равна нулю. Я традиционно ставлю 0.5W или 1W. 
0.25W ставить не пробовал, не исключено, что будет работать.
Успехов!

---

Google translate says:

*The power of the resistors is practically not important here. The main thing here is for the resistors to withstand a high pulse current (for R1: Ipuls = Umax / R1 ~ 1A or Ppuls ~ 300W). But the average power is almost zero. I traditionally put 0.5W or 1W. 0.25W did not try to install, it is possible that it will work. Wish you Successes!*

Comment: I beg your pardon? I think answers are supposed to be in English here. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.